# PyQt4 app button not working

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to set up an app in Linux using `PyQt4` designer and I'm struggling to connect signals and slots to it. Right now all I want it to do is connect a button `clicked` signal to a custom slot, `saveEnergyScheme` which simply prints 'energy list' to the terminal.

I've translated the .ui code for my app to a python class with `pyuic4 -w sumcorr.ui > sumcorr_ui.py`. This created a class in the `sumcorr_ui.py` module called `SumCorr_ui`:

```
class SumCorr_ui(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_SumCorr_ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, f=QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags()):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent, f)

        self.setupUi(self)
```

I then made my app as a custom widget and tried to add a simple signal-slot connection to a button to show it works:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from sumcorr_ui import SumCorr_ui

class SumCorr(SumCorr_ui):

    def __init__(self):
        SumCorr_ui.__init__(self)
        self.save_energies_button.clicked.connect(self.saveEnergyScheme)

    def saveEnergyScheme(self):
        print 'energyList'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mySumCorr = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = SumCorr()
    ui.setupUi(mySumCorr)
    mySumCorr.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I expect to get the line 'energy list' when I click the button named `save_energies_button`, but nothing happens. Could this be because I haven't built the UI as a widget, but as a main window? Why doesn't it print out??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `ui.show()` and you'll see that your code is creating two different windows, one should have the signal connected and one doesn't. That's because you are showing only the `mySumCorr` window, but you call only `setupUi` on it, which does not connect the signal.

When you create the `SumCorr` instance, you are creating a window and setting it up, then, by no reason, you do `ui.setupUi(mySumCorr)`, which setups the `mySumCorr` instance *without* connecting the signal, and you show this last window.

I believe your code should be like this:

```
class SumCorr(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_SumCorr_ui):

    def __init__(self):
        SumCorr_ui.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.save_energies_button.clicked.connect(self.saveEnergyScheme)

    def saveEnergyScheme(self):
        print 'energyList'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mySumCorr = SumCorr()
    mySumCorr.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that it doesn't make any sense to have a `SumCorr_ui` class, that's because `Qt` *is* a UI library so you are just introducing a worthless level of abstraction. The designer file already gives you an abstraction over the ui layout.

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented your version and it works! I did not realise that I was creating two windows. Looks like I need to do a bit more reading.....

Comment: Why is it redundant? One is generated by pyuic4 and that code should not be edited manually.

Comment: @LtWorf No. The `Ui_SumCorr_ui` is generated by pyuic. The OP used it to create a `SumCorr_ui` class which simply inherits by both `QMainWindow` and `Ui_SumCorr_ui` and finally the `SumCorr` class that inherits from this `SumCorr_ui`.